# Webscoket asp.net core read large file data

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, c#-2.0, file-sharing

want to share a file using WebSocket in .netcore..
but its working fine for the small files ...till to 200kb approximately or may be less.

but when we send the large file like 1mb then it broke into many chunks... and every chunk revived at client side... at that time... but now I want to read full byte array and then send back to client.. I don't understand how to read all byte for full file.. here is sample data...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgQXY.jpg)

```
    public override async Task ReceiveAsync(WebSocket socket, WebSocketReceiveResult result, byte[] buffer)
    {



        var socketId = WebSocketConnectionManager.GetId(socket);
       // var message = $"{socketId} said: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count)}"; 
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer ,  0 , result.Count);

        await SendMessageToAllAsync(base64);

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to get all the data in a single message?

Comment: yes i wan to get whole file size and send it to back client..